# Website goes unresponsive after directing to https in nginx server

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, https

I have a web application in django framework and I have setup an nginx server to serve the site. I have also setup SSL into the site. The site works fine with both http and https.

Now I want to direct all http requests to https so my users always use the secure version.

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/SSL;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/SSL/key;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /site_media/static/ {
        alias /home/user/folder/static/dist/;
    }
    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/tmp/site.sock;
    }
}
```

Now when I insert a 301 redirect to https and restart the server, the site goes unresponsive.

```
return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

into my

```
server { ... }
```

Any idea how to fix this issue, any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing an unprotected `return` statement into the server block will attempt to redirect both the `http` and `https` sites, resulting in a loop. You could place the `return` statement inside an `if` block and detect when the protocol is not `https`, or the more common solution is split the configuration across two `server` blocks, for example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/SSL;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/SSL/key;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /site_media/static/ {
        alias /home/user/folder/static/dist/;
    }
    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/tmp/site.sock;
    }
}
```